# If I have a valid C1 (transit) visa for USA do I require UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I am an Indian passport holder and will be travelling from New Delhi to Lima via London and Miami. I have a short layover of 3hrs in London in going to Lima and while coming back. My questions are:

1. If I have a valid C1 visa for USA do I still require transit visa (DATV) for UK?
2. My baggage will be checked through to Lima and I will not be leaving the border control area. I will be coming back in 20 days. Since C1 is multi entry, will no visa for UK be still applicable while coming back?

Comment: Please visit the link for further information on your query https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/527411/UK_Visa_requirements_3_June_2016.pdf

Comment: the link mentions the following exemption: a valid visa for entry to Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA (whether or
not the holder is travelling to or from these countries); - does this holds true if I have a C1 visa?

Comment: @Suhail Yes it does, **any** US visa will do